# Sum of lengths of each of a matrix's diagonals given a point's coordinates

Tags: matrices

Consider the following matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}
O & I & O & O & O \\
O & O & I & O & I \\
O & O & O & P & O \\
O & O & I & O & I \\
O & I & O & O & O
\end{bmatrix}$

I'm looking for an expression for the number of elements $I$ in diagonals of the matrix at point $P$.

Can anyone propose an elegant expression?

PS: Matrix is always a square one, and P can be any of the cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $N*N$ the dimensions of the matrix, and $P$ has coordinates $(r_p, c_p)$.

The lengths of each diagonal segment are:

$topRight = min(N - r_p, N - c_p)$

$topLeft = min(N - r_p, c_p - 1)$

$bottomRight = min(r_p - 1, N - c_p)$

$bottomLeft = min(r_p - 1, c_p - 1)$

Thus the total number of $I$ is the sum of the four lengths above.